# Laravel 5 Search and pagination url's together

Tags: laravel, search, scope, pagination, eloquent

I have a search button and pagination system. They are working perfectly. But when i searched something and page was paginated with numbers. After clicking next page. Search query is gone. After that all values are coming into page2. Not searched values.

My search button changing url like this `/en/news?q=foo`

My pagination is changing url like this(default btw) `/en/news?page=2`

How can i add this side by side. Or how can i solve the problem. I am open any solution.

I am using scope for search.

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $search) {
    return $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' .$search. '%')
        ->orWhere('sub_body', 'like', '%' .$search. '%')
        ->orWhere('body', 'like', '%' .$search. '%');
}
```

Also this is my controller:

```
public function index (Request $request){

    $localeCode = LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale();
    $updates = Update::latest()->take(3)->get();
    $query = $request->get('q');
    if ($query){
        $new = $query ? News::search($query)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10):News::all();
        return  view('frontend.news', compact('localeCode', 'updates', 'new', 'query'));
    }
    else
    {
        $new = News::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
        return  view('frontend.news', compact('localeCode', 'updates', 'new', 'query'));
    }

}
```

I hope i can express my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is explained in the documentation for [displaying pagination results](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/session.php#L125):

> **Appending To Pagination Links**
>
> You may append to the query string of pagination links using the appends method. For example, to append sort=votes to each pagination link, you should make the following call to  appends:
>
> ```
> {{ $users->appends(['sort' => 'votes'])->links() }}
> ```

---

I find your current code quite confusing. I think you can rewrite it like this

```
public function index (Request $request){
    $localeCode = LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale();
    $updates = Update::latest()->take(3)->get();
    $query = $request->get('q');

    $new = $request->filled('q') ? News::search($query) : News::query();
    $new = $new->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);

    return view('frontend.news', compact('localeCode', 'updates', 'new', 'query'));
}
```

and in the view you'll have to use

```
{{ $new->appends(['q' => $query])->links() }}
```

Comment: @AliÖzen I added some more code to the answer, maybe it is of help for you. Reason I rewrote the method is that you basically did two times the same stuff on different query builders, which can be cumbersome if you extend the functionality of your paginated list in future (because you always have to do it twice). With the above, you should be able to do all at once.

Comment: Search + pagination working perfectly right now. But i am looking at yours right now. Thanks again. Mines are very complicated. You are right.

Answer (score 5):

```
{{ $users->appends($_GET)->links() }}
```

that append all your filter value in one line

Answer (score 0):

Try to use {{ $collection->appends(request()->all())->links() }}